# SQL returning sqlite3 cursor object instead of value

Tags: python, sql, database

I'm trying to retrieve a password from a user table, but when I assign a SELECT to the variable pw_august_borne, it returns as an sqlite3.Cursor object. I need it to return the password associated with August Borne, and I found that using a for loop to iterate over THE ONE SINGLE VALUE in the variable pw_list returns the wanted output. I know I could just use the iteration method brigade it is a tuple, but I want to find a better way. What do you recommend? 
Output after running script:
`helloWORLD
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0xb6314720>`

````
conn = sqlite3.connect ('login_test2.db')

c = conn.cursor ()

'''lists all passwords (pw) in users_tbl'''
pw_list = c.execute ("SELECT pw FROM users_tbl WHERE name='August Borne'")
for row in pw_list :
    print (row[0])

pw_august_borne = c.execute ('SELECT pw FROM users_tbl WHERE name="August Borne"')
print (pw_august_borne)

conn.close ()```
````

Comment: Also, if I use a generator to print it, I get `<generator object <genexpr> at 0xb63148b0>`. What's the difference?

Comment: Your first version looks correct (the second is not).  What is your question?

Comment: I just thought at first that it should return the same thing, but now I see that because it's a tuple is simply returning the fact that is a tuple in pw_august_borne

Comment: Is `helloWORLD` August Borne's password?

Comment: Yes, it is. That's what I thought I could obtain using pw_august_borne but it just shows is an object.

Answer (score 1):

use list() to get the details other than the cursor object.

```
pw_august_borne = c.execute ('SELECT pw FROM users_tbl WHERE name="August Borne"')
print(list(pw_august_borne))
```